# as3 - Error #1009, an object is null and bugged with timer

Tags: actionscript-3

When the player touches the door, the next level is supposed to be added and the previous level should be removed. However in the game, the next level does get added and everything works, but the output shows this issue.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

This is the enterframe:

```
if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(door0))
        {
            var timer: Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fade);
            timer.reset();
            timer.start();
        }
```

This is the timer:

```
function fade(event: TimerEvent)
    {
        removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fade);

        var pageTwo: PageTwo = new PageTwo;
        parent.addChild(pageTwo);
        this.parent.removeChild(this);

    }
```

This is in the "previous level" class. "this" is itself (previous level) and "pageTwo" is (next level).

So, the output indicates the error is at "parent.addChild(pageTwo);". However if I remove that, the output indicates the issue is from "this.parent.removeChild(this);

I assume it's because the child is removed that's why there is a null issue. But how do I solve this error coming from the output? Am I removing the movieclip the wrong way?

Comment: can it be that your `ENTER_FRAME` condition creates more than one timer?

Comment: @www0z0k I was writing my answer when you've put your comment ;) Yes, I think that's the problem too.

Comment: Not an answer, but it does seem better to let the parent handle the adding and removing of `Page` objects (e.g. `PageTwo`). Your `Page` objects could dispatch a custom event object to the parent, who will handle the adding/removing of the right pages. For garbage collection purposes, it would also call a `myPageObject.kill()` function before removing a `Page` object, which removes all listeners/timers/... inside the `Page` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from this line :

```
parent.addChild(pageTwo);
```

because in your code as this condition

```
if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(door0))
```

is true, you will create another `Timer` object which when its `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` event is fired, it will try to add a new `PageTwo` instance to a `null` parent and that's why the error is fired.

So to avoid that, you can remove the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener at the first time when that condition is true or if you still need it (the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener) you have to verify your condition to avoid such behavior.

Also, your `timer` var should be declared as global to be accessible from the `fade()` function to be able to remove its `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` event listener which you are trying to remove from your current object.

Hope that can help.